# Open app from App Store not the same as in board

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a 'Terms and Conditions'  controller I represent in the first launch of the app, but when opening the app in the first time from the App Store page the Terms and Conditions'  controller not shown- only after I close the app and reopen it from the device itself (not the App Store page) then the controller is shown.

this code is from the launched screen controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [self agreedToServerTerms];

} 

- (void)agreedToServerTerms {
    [[HttpUtils instance] httpRequest:TERMS_AGREEMENT_URL :params completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        @try {
            bool acceptTerms = false;
            if (error) {
                [Utils log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"agreedToServerTerms error=%@", error]];
            } else {
                NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
                if (!error) {
                    acceptTerms = [jsonData.allValues[0] boolValue];
                    if (!acceptTerms) {
                        TermsAndConditionController *tac = [[TermsAndConditionController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TermsAndConditionController" bundle:nil];
                        tac.delegate = self;
                        [[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] pushViewController:tac animated:false];
                    }
                    else {
                        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(initialApp) withObject:nil];
                    }

                    
                } else {
                    [Utils log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"parsing jsonData error = %@" ,error]];
                    
                }
            }
        } @catch (NSException *e) {
            [Utils log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Exception occurred: %@, %@", e, [e userInfo]]];
        } 

    }];
}
```

from App delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
 LaunchScreenController *bbp = [[LaunchScreenController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LaunchScreenController" bundle:nil];
[[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] pushViewController:bbp animated:YES];
if (_launchedURL) {
    bbp.launchedURL = _launchedURL;
}

[self.window addSubview:bbp.view];
}
```

Comment: Maybe show how you launch the app or how you launch this specific controller

Comment: added, I checked it in ipads too but there the app opens as expected when opening from App Store

Comment: I think you need to do it a bit differently - how depends on the rest of your app. I don't think you should add a subview to the window here. Rather, in the first VC that is presented, perform some check there and then present your TnC VC. I'll post an example ...

Answer (score 0):

herewith how I do almost the exact same thing. I think you need to rework yours, it could be a bit different, but this may help.

In the first VC that my app displays, in its `viewWillAppear` message, I have the following code

```
    // Terms of use
    if ( [NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults integerForKey:@"tou"] != 20170614 )
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"tou" sender:nil];
        [NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults setInteger:20170614 forKey:@"tou"];
    }
```

This uses user defaults to note if the terms of use have ever been presented and, if so, it marks `@"tou"` with some arbitrary value. In your case you can set the logic in your controller and only mark it once the user accepts.

This requires a segue in the storyboard called `@"tou"` that will present your T&C controller and you may need to prevent exit if the user does not agree, but the idea is to segue away from your first VC if the user did not agree yet to present the user with the T&C rather than injecting it into the app delegate as you do at present.